# Unwanted spaces added to strings sent over TCP

Tags: go

I'm attempting to learn Go, and the first thing I've tried is sending files between a client and server using TCP. I set up a connection using `net.Listen`, and connect using `net.Dial`. My client logic is:

1. Send an int64 using `binary.Write` describing the size of the filename
2. Send the filename using `io.WriteString`
3. Send an int64 describing the size of the file
4. Send the file using `io.CopyN`

My server logic is:

1. Read 8 bytes using `binary.Read`, save as `N`
2. Read `N` bytes to get the filename, which is read into a `bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, filenameSize))` that has `String()` subsequently called on it
3. Read 8 bytes to get the filesize, save as `M`
4. `io.CopyN` from the connection into a new file object for `M` bytes.

My problem is something totally baffling to me, which I haven't been able to solve or understand, and for which I can find no discussion or solution on Google or SO: even though the filename length is transmitted accurately, the server always receives a filename of twice the expected length, where the first half is whitespace. Even more bafflingly, using `strings.TrimLeft(filename, " ")` never works, even though it works for strings I create myself.

So I have absolutely no idea what's going on, and nothing in the docs, SO, Google, go-nuts, etc mentions anything that could seem relevant. No idea how to move forward or think about this problem, I'd love some help.

My server handler:

```
func handle(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 30))

    var filenameSize int64
    err := binary.Read(conn, binary.LittleEndian, &filenameSize)
    check(err)

    filename := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, filenameSize))
    bytesRead, err := io.CopyN(filename, conn, filenameSize)
    fmt.Printf("Expected %d bytes for filename, read %d bytes\n", filenameSize, bytesRead)
    str := filename.String()
    fmt.Println(strings.TrimLeft(str, " "))

    var filesize int64
    err = binary.Read(conn, binary.LittleEndian, &filesize)
    check(err)
    fmt.Printf("Expecting %d bytes in file\n", filesize)

    f, err := os.Create(str)
    check(err)
    bytesWritten, err := io.CopyN(f, conn, filesize)
    check(err)
    fmt.Printf("Transfer complete, expected %d bytes, wrote %d bytes", filesize, bytesWritten)
    if filesize != bytesWritten {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR! File doesn't match expected size!")
    }
}
```

My client:

```
func main() {
    name := "test_file.doc"

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8250")
    check(err)

    length := int64(len(name))
    err = binary.Write(conn, binary.LittleEndian, length)
    check(err)

    bytes, err := io.WriteString(conn, name)
    check(err)
    if bytes != len(name) {
        fmt.Printf("Error! Wrote %d bytes but length of name is %d!\n", bytes, length)
    }

    f, err := os.Open(name)
    check(err)

    stat, err := f.Stat()
    check(err)

    filesize := stat.Size()
    err = binary.Write(conn, binary.LittleEndian, filesize)
    check(err)

    bytesWritten, err := io.CopyN(conn, f, filesize)
    check(err)
    if bytesWritten != filesize {
        fmt.Printf("Error! Wrote %d bytes but length of file is %d!\n", bytes, stat.Size())
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example: [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're reading fixed size data for the filename, just call `Read`with the correct size slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Allocation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation)
>
> Making slices, maps and channels
>
> ```
> Call             Type T     Result
>
> make(T, n)       slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity n
> make(T, n, m)    slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity m
> ```

---

> [Package bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/)
>
> ```
> import "bytes"
> ```
>
> [func NewBuffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer)
>
> func NewBuffer(buf []byte) *Buffer
>
> NewBuffer creates and initializes a new Buffer using buf as its
>   initial contents. The new Buffer takes ownership of buf, and the
>   caller should not use buf after this call. NewBuffer is intended to
>   prepare a Buffer to read existing data. It can also be used to size
>   the internal buffer for writing. To do that, buf should have the
>   desired capacity but a length of zero.
>
> In most cases, new(Buffer) (or just declaring a Buffer variable) is
>   sufficient to initialize a Buffer.

---

`bytes.NewBuffer` can be used to size the internal buffer for writing. To do that, buf should have the desired capacity but a length of zero. For example, with a length of zero and a capacity of filenameSize,

```
filename := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, filenameSize))
```

In error, you allocated buf with a length and capacity of filenameSize,

```
filename := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, filenameSize))
```

Answer (score 2):

The line in the server handler

```
filename := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, filenameSize))
```

is wrong, repace it by

```
var filename bytes.Buffer
```

The expression `make([]byte, filenameSize)` creates an slice with initial
*length* `filenameSize` filled with the null value of type `byte`, so `0`. `bytes.NewBuffer` creates a buffer with initial contents of this slice and will append to this. So you don't receive to much, you start with too much.

See [golang language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)
for `make`.
See [package bytes doc](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) about `bytes.newBuffer`, it explicitly states that you need *length* zero but positive *capacity* if you intend to hand a buffer for some preallocation scheme.

Comment: In this case, `filename := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, filenameSize))`, a precise allocation, is more efficient than `var filename bytes.Buffer`.